# How to remove a layer in openlayer 4

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoext

I am trying to remove a layer from a layerGroup. However I dont know how to proceed. I have a button where on click of the button , the layer should be removed from the list.

```
   olMap.getLayers().forEach(function(layer, i) 
{
    if (layer instanceof ol.layer.Group) 
    {
         layer.getLayers().forEach(function(sublayer, j) 
         {
            if(sublayer instanceof ol.layer.Tile)
            {
                 if(count==0)
                 {
                     layer.getLayers().remove();
                 }
            }
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: To gives users the bet chance of answering the question, please include some code of what you have tried and specifically what isn't working

Comment: var layer=olMap.getLayerGroup();
var layers=olMap.getLayers();
var newLayers;
for (var i=0;i<layers.length;i++){
if(i!=0){
newLayers=newLayers+layer[i];
}
}
olMap.setLayers(newLayers);

Comment: The comments section isn’t the best place for code. You can edit the question as much as you like to provide clarity